# MDM profile installation check

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mdm

I am making an application which installs a MDM profile on the device. The profile is getting installed successfully from the server. 
But if the user cancels the profile installation then i have no way to check from the application that profile is installed successfully or not..

Now i need a way to check from the application if that profile is installed successfully or not?
Can i check the installation status from my application?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to check the profiles installed from an App but you can check the profiles installed using MDM